# Tween over using maxScrollH

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tween, gsap

i wanna do something like a tween that scrolls over infinitely,

when it reaches the end starts over just the letters that has finished.

like a carousel.

i've tryed this :

```
TweenMax.to(object, 2, {scrollH:object.maxScrollH+10,yoyo:true,repeat:-1});
```

this is almost what i want.

Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with the approach you've shown? You don't want it to play backwards after reaching the end? Then just remove yoyo or set it to false

Comment: i want something like this.. when the first letter on the right side reaches the end it continues until desapear then just this letter appears again on the left side, and goes on letter by letter